# stackpanel with usercontrol and itemsource shows newitemplaceholder

Tags: c#, wpf, user-controls, itemscontrol

Im about to create a diagram designer, and have create nodes and edges as usercontrols.
I have an stackpanel where I want to place them. I have managed to make it works with the following code:

```
<Window.Resources>
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type Model:Node}">
        <Canvas>
            <View:NodeUserControl></View:NodeUserControl>
        </Canvas>
    </DataTemplate>
 </Window.Resources>

<StackPanel Name="DisplayArea">
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Nodes}" >
</ItemsControl>
</StackPanel>
```

Where Nodes is an observablecollection

But this also shows an {NewItemPlaceholder} text and I can't figure out why. Would really appreciate if someone could point out my mistake.

EDIT: I have tried to create a new solution with just the beforementioned code and this doenst show the [NewItemPlaceholder}. Now Im really confused can't see the difference and what else that would cause this.

Comment: on which control the `{NewItemPlaceholder}` is shown? Or I misunderstand your words?

Comment: Please learn WPF, by creating some `Hello, World!` type of stuff before getting into complex stuff.

Comment: Can you try manually assigning your DataTemplate as ItemTemplate first? What does it show?

Comment: @KingKing the stackpanel

Comment: @HighCore I have gone through several basic tutorials, but probally not enough. Do you have a solution to my problem?

Answer (score 0):

I got the same issue and the cause was that die source data was bound twice: One time to a DataGrid control and a second bound to an ItemsControl. The ItemsControl shows its items on a canvas and also {NewItemPlaceholder} becomes visible there.
The solution was to avoid adding new items to the DataGrid by:

ok. I didn't need adding.